# How to set 4.5 stars with jQuery on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make sure that when the page is loaded, the rating is automatically filled with 4.5. There must be four and a half stars active (yellow) with jQuery.

My code:

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

    fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }


    /****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

    .rating { 
      border: none;
      float: left;
    }

    .rating > input { display: none; } 
    .rating > label:before { 
      margin: 5px;
      font-size: 1.25em;
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      display: inline-block;
      content: "\f005";
    }

    .rating > .half:before { 
      content: "\f089";
      position: absolute;
    }

    .rating > label { 
      color: #ddd; 
    float: right; 
    }

    /***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

    .rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
    .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
    .rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

    .rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
    .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
    .rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
    .rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="star" value="5" classe="fa"><label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="star" value="4.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="star" value="4" classe="fa"><label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="star" value="3.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="star" value="3" classe="fa"><label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="star" value="2.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="star" value="2" classe="fa"><label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="star" value="1.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="star" value="1" classe="fa"><label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="star" value="0.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
    </fieldset>
```

What can I do in jQuery to give 4.5 stars to this?

Comment: document.getElementById('star4half').click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to set the value directly in the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="star4half" checked name="star" value="4.5"
```

using the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#htmlattrdefchecked) attribute.

If you need to use jquery, your `radio` (in the code provided in the question) has an `id` so you can select it using the id and use `.prop`, wrap in a doc ready to be safe:

```
$(() => { 
    $("#star4half").prop("checked", true) 
});
```

If you don't have an id, eg if you have multiple ratings on your page, then you can identify them using the value, eg:

```
$(".rating > [value='4.5']").prop("checked", true)
```

(make sure the `4.5` is in quotes otherwise it gets an error)

Updated snippet with id:

```js
$(() => {
  $("#star4half").prop("checked", true)
});
```

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}


/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="star5" name="star" value="5" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="star" value="4.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star4" name="star" value="4" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="star" value="3.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star3" name="star" value="3" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="star" value="2.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star2" name="star" value="2" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="star" value="1.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="star1" name="star" value="1" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="star" value="0.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Snippet without id

```js
$(() => {
  $(".rating [value='4.5']").prop("checked", true)
});
```

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}


/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #FFD700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #FFED85;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="5" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="4.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="4" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="3.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="3" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="2.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="2" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="1.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="1" classe="fa"><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" value="0.5" classe="fa"><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out I couldn't target the star icons directly to apply the selected styles so I added ID tags to the label elements containing the icons. Here's the jQuery I added:

```
window.onload = function() {
        if (window.jQuery) {  
            //$("#s1").css("color", "#FFD700");
            $("#star-half").click();
            $("#star-1").click();
            $("#star-1-half").click();
            $("#star-2").click();
            $("#star-2.5").click();
            $("#star-3").click();
            $("#star-3-half").click();
            $("#star-4").click();
            $("#star-4-half").click();
        }
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<fieldset class="rating bg-light">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="star" value="5" classe="fa"><label id="star-5" class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="star" value="4.5" classe="fa"><label id="star-4-half" class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="star" value="4" classe="fa"><label id="star-4" class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="star" value="3.5" classe="fa"><label id="star-3-half" class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="star" value="3" classe="fa"><label id="star-3" class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="star" value="2.5" classe="fa"><label id="star-2-half" class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="star" value="2" classe="fa"><label id="star-2" class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="star" value="1.5" classe="fa"><label id="star-1-half" class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="star" value="1" classe="fa"><label id="star-1" class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="star" value="0.5" classe="fa"><label id="star-half" class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to do it based on `value=4.5` so you don't need an `id`

Comment: @freedomn-m I like your approach better. +1 to your answer.